# Action bar menu color is being applied on all the app rather on the menu only

Tags: android

I am following a simple [tutorial](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/styling-the-actionbar-part-2/) how to change the color of the action bar

when I add the below code in my "style" file, the background will turn all of it to blue. I only need the color to be on the action bar.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

</style>
 <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:background">#87CEFA</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and this is the manifest.

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyActionBarTheme"
                 >
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `MyActionBarTheme` in your manifest. This will set the background of your entire app. Rather, continue to use `AppTheme`. As the tutorial says, you should reference `MyActionBarTheme` by adding `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>` to `AppTheme`. This ensures that the background you set only applies to the action bar style.